# do all two manifolds admit a three-colorable triangulation?

Tags: co.combinatorics, at.algebraic-topology

A triangulation of a two-manifold $M$ is three-colorable if all vertices of the triangulation can be colored red, green, or blue without any two adjacent vertices having the same color.

My question: do all two-manifolds admit a three-colorable triangulation?

Answer (score 24):

Sure. Start with an arbitrary triangulation $T$, and then takes its [barycentric subdivision](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Barycentric_subdivision) $T'$. That means that the vertices of $T'$ come in three types: (1) vertices of $T$, (2) midpoints of edges of $T$ and (3) centers of faces of $T$.

Color these three types red, blue and green respectively.

Comment: Indeed. Any superficial resemblance to four-color-type problems is misleading. :)